# Need help creating a Azure Bot service

Tags: azure

Click Create new resource link found on the upper left-hand corner of the Azure portal, then select AI + Machine Learning > Web App bot. After filling all the details, I get an error message stating 'the service id is not available' and the create button disappears.

Comment: The exact error message is: 'The requested bot ID is not available.'

Comment: It means that you have already created a bot with the same name. Try creating a new bot with a different bot name and you won't get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Sign out and re-login to the Azure portal and then re-try the operation has mentioned in the below article 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Make sure you have enough amount in your Azure subscription (or) your subscription is Active.Like(changing "consumption plan" to "app service plan.)

However Azure Portal is a simple GUI to create any resources easily. But it doesn't mean to stop you from using other ways like Azure CLI, Powershell, ARM templates, Other SDK's
[Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/bot-service/index?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) to create a WebApp Bot

[Dot Net SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-sdk-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to create a WebApp Bot

[Node.js SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/bot-service/javascript/bot-builder-javascript-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to create a webApp Bot

Additional information: After you've registered [your client with Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#register-your-client-application-with-azure-ad), you need to [create the Web App.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdate) Be sure to use the following in the body:kind "webapp"
location Geographic location used to create the bot service resources. For example, eastus, westus, westus2, and so on.
You won't be able to test this due to Azure subscription limitations.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because the service name has already been assigned within Azure. That name must be unique across all Azure services, not only the ones in your group or resource groups. This is a common error new comers may experience.